# UserControl in vb6.0 getting border in Windows 7

Tags: user-controls, vb6

In my VB6 application, a `UserControl` is used. Recently we moved to Windows 7 from Windows XP. In Windows 7 the `UserControl` is getting borders on the top and the left.
Please tell me how to remove those borders.

Ii have attached the image below.
On top of the `UserControl` there is a `ListBox`. On the `UserControl`, the top and left borders are visible.

[image]

Comment: Can you show us a screenshot from each OS, showing the difference? I can't imagine what you're talking about.

Comment: And now I'm even more confused. How in the world are you producing that output in VB 6? Are you using drawing functions to simulate a console window? If so, why?

Comment: Are these UC borders? Maybe it is UC placement (and you see some background); you may have screen set to 120dpi, which causes twips per pixel change from 15 to 12 and if your placement code uses both pixels and twips, then it may get confused. Same comment actually applies to drawing code either :)

Comment: Is that the border of the usercontrol itself or is it the border of a control on the usercontrol? ... Could you post an image in which the form, and the usercontrol, and anything has a different background color? that way you can find out where the border belongs to.

Comment: Especially as the text seems to be truncated, I'd suggest a DPI miscalculation with "large fonts".

Comment: You're maybe getting the borders because of different display settings - somewhere in Win7 there's an option that you didn't have turned on in XP.  Make sure that the VB6 control doesn't have any borders?

Answer (score 1):

Without code it is hard to tell, but perhaps you are using Width and Height instead of [ScaleWidth and ScaleHeight](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa445663%28v=vs.60%29.aspx) in your painting?  The latter will give you the size of the client area you are working with.

Again, just a guess until we see some code.